# Django restart server or httpd

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls, django-views

In django framework,When there are changes in urls.py or model.py or views.py .We would restart httpd.

But as the documentation says we could restart runserver to get the latest changes.

Which is the best efficient way for doing the above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

runserver.py restarts automatically every time you modify any .py file, but when you are using apache you have to restart the proccess manually.

Answer (score 5):

`touch your_project_name.wsgi` and save without any change.
It will change data modify and django will automatically reloading code.

Answer (score 1):

`runserver` refers to the development server that is distributed with Django. Restarting this one or your httpd are the same thing, in both cases you restart the webserver. If you're using apache, you are not using the development server that is startet by `runserver.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Type `fg` in terminal to take job front and then type `Ctr+c` to stop server and then run

```
Python manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 0):

For the development server, I added this very convenient function. Obviously, you should never leave this in prod.

```
from _thread import interrupt_main
def shutdown(_):
    # Clean up and then...
    interrupt_main()
    return redirect("/")
```

_thread.interrupt_main() simulates a KeyboardInterrupt (SIGINT).